# Run a function every 5 minutes starting from a particular wall clock time

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks

I want to run a function every 5 minutes starting at a particular wall clock time.

I have implemeneted threading.timer which runs every 5 minutes (interval) but I don't know how to start this timer at a particular time.

```
from threading import Timer


class BSOJobScheduler(object):

    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer = None
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.daemon = True
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to that is using Time.time() so I will use that.

You start timer like this:
`start = Time.time()`
And end like this:
`end = Time.time()`
Then to get value of time you will just subtract `start` from `end` like this:
`value = end - start`
You have to do like this becouse `start = Time.time()` gets value from computer so your next step is get another value from computer `end = Time.time()` and just subtract it.

And you just checking if `value` >= 300 (300secounds is 5minutes).

Answer (score 0):

One of the threads could do someting like this:

```
INTERVAL = 5 * 60

next_run = time.monotonic() # better than time.time()
while True:                 # or while not stop_condition:
    my_function()           # should not take more time than the INTERVAL
    next_run += INTERVAL
    sleep_time = next_run - time.monotonic()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```